# Vue-test-utils loading dependencies - Vue3

Tags: vue.js, testing, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I'm developing some tests for single file components in **VueJs**. These components use **font-awesome**.

This is my **App**, as you can see I have fontawesome available for all child components.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(fas);

createApp(App)
.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
.mount('#app');
```

Here's a test

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import ListComponent from '@/components/ListComponent.vue'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';

let someData = [{
  name: 'Some person name', 
  key: '2222222',
  moreInfo: [
    {title: 'aa'},
    {title: 'bb'},
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Some other person name', 
  key: '12321123,
  moreInfo: [
    {title: 'cc'},
    {title: 'x'},
  ]
},
}];

let wrapper = mount(ListComponent, {
  propsData: {
    someData
  },
  stubs: {
    'font-awesome-icon': FontAwesomeIcon
  }
});

describe('ListadoImputados.vue', () => {.... tests ....});
```

*Test details are not important*, I don't know how to **add / include font-awesome-icon** in the context so i can avoid getting the following warnings

```
console.warn node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:40
    [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: font-awesome-icon
```

I tried adding this dependency as a mock and stub but no luck. Also importing Fontawesome at the top of the file does not work, the warning is still showing. I was thinking maybe in creating a vue app in the test file and inject the component like this

```
createApp(App)
.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
.mount('#app');
```

but I'm copying and pasting code and I'm not sure this is the right way.
Is there a way to add this dependencies to my test context?
I'm using Vue 3, vue-test-utils + jest

Comment: If `FontAwesomeIcon` is not relevant for your tests, all you need is `stubs: { FontAwesomeIcon: true }`, without importing it. To automatically stub all subcomponents, you can specify `shallow: true` in `mount`'s options. It's the equivalent of going through the entire list of sub-components and assigning `true` to them (that's what `shallow: true` does).

Comment: The error you're seeing is not directly related to the test. It's related to the test environment not being able to resolve `FontAwesomeIcon` - it's likely a path error. Once you provide the correct path to it (or fix whatever it is that's failing the import), what you have should start working.

Comment: i forgot to tell that I need the complete mounting, not shallow, because my tests are going deeper. I don't care testing fontawesome. I know what you mean, but my tests are failing if I used shallowMounting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue Test Utils v2 (for Vue 3), the `stubs` mounting option is moved into [`global.stubs`](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-stubs). Also note that a stub does nothing by definition, so stubbing the component only requires providing the component name.

Your mounting options should look like this:

```js
const wrapper = mount(ListComponent, {
  global: {
    stubs: ['FontAwesomeIcon']
  }
})
```

If for some reason you *need* the actual component, you could technically provide the component definition as a "stub", but you'd also need to initialize the icons for it as you would in the app's startup:

```js
// assume only `faUserSecret` icon used in `ListComponent`
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faUserSecret)

//...

const wrapper = mount(ListComponent, {
  global: {
    stubs: { FontAwesomeIcon }
  }
})
```